# Very slow performance on thousands of millions records in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-slow-query-log

```
id    market_id      date          keyword                 sku            a             b         c  
1        1        2019-01-01    some text for this      QAB-XU-VV        3.1           2.4       3.5
2        2        2019-01-02    some text for text      ABC-XA-VV        2.1           4.1       1.2
```

This is an instance of table `A`

```
`id` : `int primary key auto increment`
`market_id` : `int(4)`  `INDEX`
`date` : `date`   `INDEX`
`keyword`: `varchar(191)` `utf8_general_ci`
`sku`: `varchar(191)` INDEX `utf8_general_ci`
`a, b, c` : `float`
```

I need to query like this

```
SELECT
  sku,
  keyword,
  market_id,
  SUM(a),
  SUM(b),
  SUM(c),
FROM A
WHERE market_id = 2 AND date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and '2020-02-02'
GROUP BY sku, keyword;
```

This query is expected about a hundred of thousand records. This query takes over 5 mins. so I used `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` but no improvements.

Please help me. Thank you.

## UPDATED:

This shows `EXPLAIN` result.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

For this query:

```
SELECT sku, keyword, market_id,
       SUM(a), SUM(b), SUM(c)
FROM A
WHERE market_id = 2 AND
      date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and '2020-02-02'
GROUP BY sku, keyword, market_id;
```

I would recommend a composite index on `A(market_id, date, sku, keyword, a, b, c)`.

This is a covering index so the original data pages do not need to be read.  You can also use `A(market_id, date)`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I will try soon but please guide me composite indexing is faster than individual indexing? so I need to remove original indexes and then create composite index again on the original table?

Comment: @AlexandrBiship . . . You can have as many indexes on the table as you need.  However, I would recommend dropping the index on `market_id` and replacing it with `(market_id, date)`.

Comment: So If I use `A(market_id, date)`, should I keep individual indexes for `sku` and `keyword` as well or drop all indexes and just use `A(market_id, date)`?

Comment: I've just tested with `A(market_id, date, sku, keyword, a, b, c)`. much improvement. count of records was about 140,000 and took time 90 seconds. `A(market_id, date) `was also similar. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This query result gets about 300,000 records so I need to use LIMIT and OFFSET. but there is no effect even if I use this. please guide me about this as well.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship . . . The `sku` and `keyword` indexes would not be used for this query, but they might be useful for other queries.  If the aggregation is *resulting in* 140,000 rows, then you have a lot of data going in.  MySQL has to sort a bunch of data for the `group by`.

Comment: I see. The updated query takes time 1 min 30 seconds and `LIMIT`  is no effect. Is there another way to improve query time? I just used `A(market_id, date)`.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship . . . I don't think so.  You are returning a lot of data that needs to be aggregated.

Comment: I just updated my question. Even If I use `LIMIT` to restrict the count of records, query time is same as getting results without `LIMIT`.

Comment: Btw, aggregated result can have `300,000` of records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207302/discussion-between-alexandr-biship-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 1):

Gordon explained most things.

Note that `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY` *usually* cause a break in the flow, thereby preventing most of the benefit of `LIMIT`.  Well, actually there is a small benefit in `LIMIT`, but it is only the transmission effort and time for delivering a different-sized resultset.

As for improving further?  As things stand with the current query and Gordon's "covering" index, no.

But...  If this is a time-series of data and you could compute subtotals for the `SUMs` each day.  Then fetching the grand total for 33 days can be made *much* faster; perhaps 10x faster.

Tentatively the summary table would have

```
PRIMARY KEY(market_id, date, sku, keyword)
```

And other columns of `sum_a, sum_b, sum_c`, and you would add new rows to the table each night.

I discuss "Summary tables" in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

For indexing tips, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Thank you @Rick James. But I need to aggregate data according to date frame that client will choose on the client side. In order words, date frame is not constant.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship - But if it is always some multiple of days or hours (or ...) then that would be the unit for summarizing.

Comment: Yes. you're right. I already have base data on another table and this table(`A`) is a summary table that is already aggregated per day. So what I just need to do is how to improve speed in this current table `A`.

Comment: I used `A(sku, keyword)` indexes for `group by` columns and query time is pretty fast(`EXPLAIN` shows this is `INDEX` scanning) but if I use high `OFFSET` along with `LIMIT`(since result can be hundreds of thousand records. so pagination is needed), then query time is getting slower.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship - How many rows are returned?  Is the "pagination" for a web page?  What about jumping to a range of SKUs instead of paginating through the entire output?  (In other words, let's look at other approaches to the speed issue.)

Comment: Thank you @Rick James. 1. About 300,000 records. 2.Yes. it's for pagination. 3. SKU is string type and it's not comparable. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship - How does the end-user find the row(s) he wants?  It could take a looooong time to page through 300K rows.  If the user has a SKU in mind, he should be able to type all or part of it and go directly to the row(s).  Please describe the "user experience" so I can focus in on what part to work on.

Comment: The end-user wants to see all results at a time without SKU or keyword input but I think I need to go with your suggestion. @Rick James

Comment: @AlexandrBiship - All 300K results??  I have trouble imagining that.  Maybe he could "download" 300K, not "display" 300K??  Let's see your `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.